# Making a TCP socket in C

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I would like to send a group of packets, like this one:

```
\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B
```

to my computer `192.168.123.45` on port `102`.

This is a little program in Ruby written yesterday, which does the job. Now I'm trying to do this in C, eventually in order to have a Windows executable file, but I'm stuck.

Does someone know how to do this Ruby program in C ? Thank you.

```
require 'socket'

myport = 102
myhost = '192.168.123.45'
mysock = TCPSocket.new(myhost, myport)

mysock.write [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04,
             0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 
             0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B].pack('C*')
puts mysock.read
mysock.close

puts "End of socket"
```

Comment: [Here's a good start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I found that by searching for "msdn sockets" in my favorite search engine.

Answer (score 5):

I refer you to the excellent tutorial by Beej: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

It won't be nearly as easy as in ruby, but you should be able to scrape something together based on the examples in there.

Comment: that's not an answer.That's a suggestion!

Comment: That answer is better, Than the answer he is asking for. The answer he asks for is this: yes, i know how to do it. But I dont have the time to make the program for you

Answer (score 2):

Refer to "Beej guide for socket programming" .
Its simple and easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using winsock library to program sockets , you can refer the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ,it has an usage code on how to establish an socket connection to an host on a particular port.

Comment: Also, similar link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741416%28v=vs.85%29.aspx